OGR_STYLE Label 'anchor position' not applying in MapInfo Tab file
I've tried creating a label feature in MapInfo using an OGR_STYLE column, but the anchor position (p:12) doesnt seem to be being applied to the label.
e.g. LABEL(f:"Arial, Helvetica", c:#FF0000, a:45, p:12, s:10g, t:"Test")
Everything appears to work except for the anchor position. The labels always seem to default to what would be p:1
Has anyone come across this?
